# Python pandas groupby not working

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I want to do a pandas groupby on pr. ticker group. in below code. In order to calculate different KPIs pr. ticker in stocklist. Here i just show the col 'Difference' from the previous day. Obviously I do not want the difference between different tickers - that makes no sense - hence the groupby. But it does not work as intended.

**A problem emerge in the output file**
The actual groupby, does not do what it is supposed to, as you may see in the below output, that col 'Difference' transgress and span the different groups in the groupby (ticker). So it calculates the diff between the last ticker-line in first group and the first ticker-line in the second group. This is not as intended. this line should be a NaN as the first line...

This is the result of the 'Difference' col in df Difference
Date

```
2015-04-09 NaN
2015-04-10 1.180000
2015-04-13 3.150000
2015-04-14 -0.980000
2015-04-15 1.280000
2015-04-16 -8.280000
2015-04-17 -8.770000
2015-04-09 -139.859995 This is not correct. The groupby does not separate the tickers as it should. This should be a NaN... not the diff between 2 different tickers!

2015-04-10 0.899994
2015-04-13 -1.130005
2015-04-14 -0.589996
2015-04-15 1.000000
2015-04-16 0.350006
2015-04-09 -139.859995
```

Any ideas as to why the 'Difference' col is not being seperated in groupby as it should in my code?

```
import pandas as pd
import time
from io import StringIO

text = """Date   Ticker        Open        High         Low   Adj_Close   Volume
    2015-04-09  vws.co  315.000000  316.100000  312.500000  311.520000  1686800
    2015-04-10  vws.co  317.000000  319.700000  316.400000  312.700000  1396500
    2015-04-13  vws.co  317.900000  321.500000  315.200000  315.850000  1564500
    2015-04-14  vws.co  320.000000  322.400000  318.700000  314.870000  1370600
    2015-04-15  vws.co  320.000000  321.500000  319.200000  316.150000   945000
    2015-04-16  vws.co  319.000000  320.200000  310.400000  307.870000  2236100
    2015-04-17  vws.co  309.900000  310.000000  302.500000  299.100000  2711900
    2015-04-20  vws.co  303.000000  312.000000  303.000000  306.490000  1629700
    2015-04-09     mmm  166.750000  167.500000  166.500000  166.630005  1762800
    2015-04-10     mmm  165.630005  167.740005  164.789993  167.529999  1993700
    2015-04-13     mmm  167.110001  167.490005  165.919998  166.399994  2022800
    2015-04-14     mmm  165.179993  166.550003  164.649994  165.809998  1610300
    2015-04-15     mmm  165.339996  167.080002  164.839996  166.809998  2092200
    2015-04-16     mmm  165.880005  167.229996  165.250000  167.160004  2721900"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), delim_whitespace=1, parse_dates=[0], index_col=0)

def Screener(group):

    def diff_calc(group):

        df['Difference'] = df['Adj_Close'].diff()
        return df['Difference']

    df['Difference'] = diff_calc(group)
    return df

if __name__ == '__main__':

    ### groupby screeener (filtering to only rel ticker group)
    grouped = df.groupby('Ticker', as_index=False) # Now doing the groupby outside the iteration...

    for name, group in grouped:
        # Testing/showing the groups...
        print ('(group)\n',name,'\n')
        print ('(group (ticker) in df)\n',group.head(10),'\n')
        df = Screener(group)
        print(60 * '=')

    # Test the first 3 rows of each group for 'Difference' col transgress groups...
    df_test = df.groupby('Ticker').head(3).reset_index().set_index('Date')
    print ('df_test (summary from df) (Output)\n',df_test,'\n')
```

Apparantly my groupby works as intended, but the intended 'Difference' col behaves erratically shown in my test-output here:

```
(group)
 mmm 

(group (ticker) in df)
            Ticker        Open        High         Low   Adj_Close   Volume
Date                                                                      
2015-04-09    mmm  166.750000  167.500000  166.500000  166.630005  1762800
2015-04-10    mmm  165.630005  167.740005  164.789993  167.529999  1993700
2015-04-13    mmm  167.110001  167.490005  165.919998  166.399994  2022800
2015-04-14    mmm  165.179993  166.550003  164.649994  165.809998  1610300
2015-04-15    mmm  165.339996  167.080002  164.839996  166.809998  2092200
2015-04-16    mmm  165.880005  167.229996  165.250000  167.160004  2721900 

============================================================
(group)
 vws.co 

(group (ticker) in df)
             Ticker   Open   High    Low  Adj_Close   Volume
Date                                                       
2015-04-09  vws.co  315.0  316.1  312.5     311.52  1686800
2015-04-10  vws.co  317.0  319.7  316.4     312.70  1396500
2015-04-13  vws.co  317.9  321.5  315.2     315.85  1564500
2015-04-14  vws.co  320.0  322.4  318.7     314.87  1370600
2015-04-15  vws.co  320.0  321.5  319.2     316.15   945000
2015-04-16  vws.co  319.0  320.2  310.4     307.87  2236100
2015-04-17  vws.co  309.9  310.0  302.5     299.10  2711900
2015-04-20  vws.co  303.0  312.0  303.0     306.49  1629700 

============================================================
df_test (summary from df) (Output)
             Ticker        Open        High         Low   Adj_Close   Volume  Date                                                                          
2015-04-09  vws.co  315.000000  316.100000  312.500000  311.520000  1686800   
2015-04-10  vws.co  317.000000  319.700000  316.400000  312.700000  1396500   
2015-04-13  vws.co  317.900000  321.500000  315.200000  315.850000  1564500   
2015-04-09     mmm  166.750000  167.500000  166.500000  166.630005  1762800   
2015-04-10     mmm  165.630005  167.740005  164.789993  167.529999  1993700   
2015-04-13     mmm  167.110001  167.490005  165.919998  166.399994  2022800   

            Difference  
Date                    
2015-04-09         NaN  
2015-04-10    1.180000  
2015-04-13    3.150000  
2015-04-09 -139.859995  This is not correct!!! This should be NaN...
2015-04-10    0.899994  
2015-04-13   -1.130005
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing your code more closely, the scope in your `Screener` function is wrong.  You're referencing `df` in that function without having passed a `df` parameter.  This means that it is operating on the `df` variable defined in a scope outside of the function, namely, the main `df`.  So you are assigning `df.diff()` of the entire `df`, not the grouped `df`.

I found it easier to:

```
df_ = df.set_index('Ticker', append=True)
df_['Difference'] = df_.groupby(level=1).Adj_Close.diff()
print df_.reset_index('Ticker')
```

[image]

Comment: @piRSqueared, Thanks so much. This really made my (midsummernights) day. Awesome. Why use multi-index though? I have taken your groupby and put it into my context, but keeps the group iteration in. This way I can call more functions in my Screener as I want. Diff is not the only part of the calculation I need on these figures...

And if I do a separate groupby per KPI as you suggest. I suspect to waste time if I run the code on millions of Time-series stock-data.